# How to fix Cross-Origin Read Blocking when calling google maps elevation api by axios from Vue js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, cors, axios

I'm trying to to use google map api in vue js project.
I'm using two google maps services:
- the first is Time zone API => works fine 
- the second is Elevation API => get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking

I verified the url works in postman 
tried to use Ajax and vue-resource

DOESN'T WORK ELEVATION API

```
axios
    .get(
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=${latitude},${longitude}&key=APIKEY`)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.result.elevation;
     })
     .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
```

WORKS TIMEZONE API

```
axios
    .get(
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=${place.latitude},${place.longitude}&timestamp=${moment().unix()}&key=APIKEY`)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.result.elevation;
     })
     .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
```

the result is :

-Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=51.49602489999999,-0.17026260000000093&key=APIKEY' from origin 'https://test.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and a warning :

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=51.49602489999999,-0.17026260000000093&key=APIKEY with MIME type application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is not for client-side consumption from script. You must use the [Maps Javascript API Elevation Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation).

Comment: I decided to make the API call server-side and consume it in the client side 
that way it is better since I can limit the call to the api (less fees to pay) and once I get the result I update it in the database